# Facing Error in positioning the Div on top of the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, css-position

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faeJe.png)

Hi,
I hope whoever reads this is in the best of health and spirit. I am facing some difficulties in positioning the divs. I want the suggestion box of highlighted div to be on top of the horizontal scroll.
I am working on React Js. I am adding my code down here. I really appreciate your help. Thanks

```
     <td>
                <div
                      style={{
                        width: "125px",
                        marginTop: "0px",
                        marginLeft: "5px",
                        marginRight: "5px",
                      }}
                    >
                    <div style={{position:"relative"}}>
                           <div
                id={"myAutocompleteParentDiv" + this.props.id}
                style={{
                  width="100%";
                  position="relative"
                }}
              >
               <input class="provider-form" autocomplete="off" id="myAutocompleteID" type="text" name="searchValue" placeholder="" value="" style="margin-left: 0px;">
    <span style="position: relative; right: 35px; top: 5px;">
<i class="my-autocomplete-search-icon"></i>
</span>
    <div id="myAutocomplete-list-cptCode0" class="myAutocomplete-items" style="max-height: 190px; overflow-y: scroll; background-color: white; width: 125px;">
<div title="searchValue" id="undefined">
<strong>822</strong>32<input type="hidden" value="82232">
</div></div>
    </div>
    
                    </div>
               </div>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add `z-index` property to your element that you want to raise to top. In your screenshot I cannot tell whether it's in a frame or iframe. If it's in a frame, no matter what trick you do on CSS the element will not be rendered outside it's own frame. Another possible problem is that the element is cropped, in which case you may need to set `overflow` property.

Ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow